# Approaches towards Marking Membership of Group?

Tags: database-design, best-practices

Given this somewhat SQL pseudo-code:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
   id      NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY,
   marked  BOOL
);
```

I'll keep track of whether ID's have been "marked" or not.

Alternatively, I've thought to alter the table to consist of a list/set, more or less:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
  id NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

such that existence in the table indicates `marked = Y`, whereas, the opposite notes `marked = N`.

In other words, to determine whether, conceptually, an `id` is "marked," I would check whether it simply existed in the table.

Is there any advantage to choosing one over the other? Also, I don't have experience with the latter type of table structure. Is it common?

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to know if an `ID` is marked or not, using your 2nd approach (not registering the ones not marked or marked) has a few more benefits than the first: less rows saved means more unused space, and a `EXISTS` or `NOT EXISTS` operation is faster than actually retrieving the row and comparing the `BOOL marked` against a `Y/N`.

There is a noticeable difference however:

- Approach 1 (using a `marked` column) has 3 possible variations of
  `foo`: `foo` exists and **is marked**, `foo` exists and **it's not marked** or foo **doesn't exist**.
- Approach 2 (just using `ID`) has only 2 variations: either `foo` exists which we assume **it's marked**, or it doesn't which we can assume that **it's either not marked** or **it doesn't exist**. This brings a problem of discerning these last two scenarios.

On another hand, if you are going to need additional information for `foo` (like most systems) you will have to add more columns to it.

- Imagine that now you need to know the date when it was marked or
  unmarked. You can track this with another table, or just add a
  `ModifiedDate` to `foo`, if on your first approach.
- Imagine that now you have another state that's "partially marked" so 
  a `BOOL`'s 2 possible values (other than NULL) is not enough. You will now need to change it to a `VARCHAR`, or an `INT` with a foreign key to another table that explains what that status is. If you had    implemented the 2nd approach, you will have to change a big part of your queries (removing the `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS`), rather than just a few literals or hard-coded numbers, which adds additional maintenance time.

Another thing to point out is the relationship of this `foo` to other entities. If another entity might relate to 1 `foo` (no more than 1) or not, then it would probably be part of that other entity's table, but on the other hand, if an instance of another entity can relate to `foo` in a `1 - N` relationship, then the foreign key must be on `foo`, which **you won't be able to add if you are using the 2nd approach**, since an unmarked `foo` has no record.

From your question title I can guess that this `foo` represents the link between a `User` and a `Group`. If that were the case, the common approach would be using a `User` table with `UserID` as PK, a `Group` table with `GroupID` as PK and a many to many breakdown table `UserByGroup` with `UserID, GroupID` as composite PK, each being a foreign key to the related table. You could store the `CreatedDate` in this table if you need additional info, for example.